# Correct way to add image related info wagtail

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I am setting up a simple site with the main purpose of having galleries of images.
Using collections to group images and display them on a specific page is how I set it up first. However I am not sure what the recommended way is to add a description.

My options I have tried are:

- [Custom page](https://docs.coderedcorp.com/wagtail-crx/advanced/advanced02.html)
  This seems as the way to handle it, however I lose the nice feature of using collections
  to generate pages. This would mean I separate info of a image into a page model, fragmenting the image from the data. I see that creating a custom image is [recommended](https://github.com/spapas/wagtail-faq), but I doubt it's for this purpose.
- [Custom image model](https://docs.wagtail.org/en/stable/advanced_topics/images/custom_image_model.html)
  This allows me to add a description field completely replaces the image model since you can only have 1 image model afaik. In a webshop like site this seems doesn't seem suitable (price, reviews, stock etc.) but since this site focuses on the image specific it seems this kind of coupling is ok.

Is the first option the way to handle this? Or how can I set this up so that a designer/user can tie data to a image without losing the base image or allow the user
to select a 'collection' with the child pages resolving a description/model related to a image.

Any tips, references or alternatives would be appreciated.

ps: I just realized this boils down to not knowing how wagtail/django does mapping db/pojo to viewmodels.

Answer (score 3):

Definitely use a custom image model. This will allow you to add a description field that will be kept with the image. It will also let you extend this to add additional fields, e.g. photo credit. Your additional fields will be added to the form used to add/edit images. [image]